# Determining which thread my task ran in while using asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have some code that looks like this:

```
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(max_concurrency)
    async def run_concurrent(invocation):
        async with sem:
            return await _run_invocation_with_timeout(invocation, timeout_seconds)

    return await asyncio.gather(
        *(run_concurrent(invocation) for invocation in invocations)
    )
```

Behind the scenes, this gives me `max_concurrency` workers running in parallel.  How can I get some unique identifier which distinguishes which "thread" the invocation is actually running on?  The reason i want this is so that I can emit some timing information in json that can be loaded into chrome://tracing so that I can visualize the parallelism of my application.

Is it sufficient to start a counter at 0, increment it every time a task starts, and decrement it when a task finishes?  Will this accurately model the way the work is scheduled by the runtime?

Comment: I believe `asyncio.current_task().get_name()` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Two problems with this: 1) It seems to be Python 3.8 only.  2) Suppose I set max_concurrency to 1 in the above example, and run 2 invocations.  Both of them would return a different name right?  I need them to be the same since they are not actually running in parallel (and can't possibly, since only 1 task is able to run at a time)

Comment: I think the older versions also had task naming, but you might need to delve into the internals to get the name. As for (2), I'm not sure what you want is doable. Separate tasks _can_ run in parallel, but if they choose to await a synchronization device such as a semaphore that serializes them, that information is simply not present in the task itself. It's sort of like having 20 OS threads synchronize on a semaphore that lets 3 of them run at the same time: each of the 20 counts as a separate thread, despite you knowing that only 3 of them can run in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user481516342 pointed out in an earlier comment, this probably isn't possible to do 100% accurately.  Through a roundabout method and sacrificing 100% correctness, I came up with something that is close enough for my purposes though, and it's surprisingly simple.

My original code now looks like this:

```
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(max_concurrency)
tasks = list(range(1, max_concurrency+1))
async def run_concurrent(invocation):
    async with sem:
        invocation.task_id = tasks.pop()
        result = await _run_invocation_with_timeout(invocation, timeout_seconds)
        tasks.insert(0, invocation.task_id)
        return result

return await asyncio.gather(
    *(run_concurrent(invocation) for invocation in invocations)
)
```

This isn't 100% accurate because if max_concurrency is say 4 my algorithm might decide that tasks A, B, and C get ids 1, 2, and 3 whereas internally they run in 2, 3, and 4.  For the purposes of visualizing the parallelism though, I think this is sufficiently close to the real thing.